# Transform row to column and Summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse, janitor

Please can anyone help me with this

I have a dataset, see below

| Merchant | value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| paul | 5 | failed |
| royal | 3 | Failed |
| servy | 56 | Success |
| servy | 33 | success |
| paul | 4 | declined |
| royal | 5 | declined |
| royal | 6 | declined |
| royal | 22 | success |
| paul | 11 | Requery declined |

what I want to do is to summarise the status column
just like using an excel pivot table where you can transform a row as a column and summarise

I want to do the same thing in R ...I'm pretty sure there must be a way to go about it using dplyr or tidyverse package or any package you know that can do it in R

In summary, I want my result to look like this table below.

| Merchant | declined | failed | Requerydeclined | Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paul | 4 | 5 | 11 |  |
| royal | 11 | 3 |  | 22 |
| servy |  |  |  | 89 |
| Total | 15 | 8 | 11 | 111 |

plus I'm a beginner in R

I will really appreciate it if I can have an answer to this request.

Thanks all

Comment: Please paste here `dput()` of your data

Comment: agreed, though a handy line for future reference it to read the table in from the clipboard `df <- read.table("clipboard", sep = '\t', header = T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data is:

```
dat <- data.frame(merchant = c("paul", "royal", "servy", "servy", "paul", "royal", "royal", "royal", "paul"),
          value = c(5, 3, 56, 33, 4, 5, 6, 22, 11),
          Status = c("failed", "failed", "success", "success", "declined", "declined", "declined", "success", "Rquery declined"))
```

The table below can be created with:

```
table <- 
  dat %>% 
  group_by(merchant, Status) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from = value)
```

You get the sums with:

```
table %>% 
  select(!merchant) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = T)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), Merchant ~ Status)
```

---

Or with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(value ~ Merchant + Status, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need `pivot_wider` for this,

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from = value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` can indeed help, namely by:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #for spread
library(stringr) #for str_to_title
df %>%
  mutate(Status = str_to_title(Status)) %>% # make failed and Failed the same
  group_by(Merchant, Status) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% #summarise so each merchant and status only has one value value
  spread(key = Status, value = value, fill = 0) #the pivot section
```

EDIT - `spread` is now outdated so here's the `pivot_wider` version.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Status = str_to_title(Status)) %>% # make failed and Failed the same
  group_by(Merchant, Status) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% #summarise so each merchant and status only has one value value
  pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from = value) #the pivot section
```

Comment: `spread` is superseeded by `pivot_wider`! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using the `dcast()` function in the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)

Merchant<-c("paul", "royal", "servy", "servy", "paul", "royal", "royal", "royal", "paul")
Value<-c(5,3,56,33,4,5,6,22,11)
Status<-c("failed", "failed", "Success", "Success", "declined", "declined", "declined", "Success", "Requery declined")

DF<-data.frame(Merchant=Merchant, Value=Value, Status=Status)

dcast(DF, Merchant~Status, fun.aggregate=sum, value.var="Value")
```